# Setting multiple if conditions in php

Tags: php, if-statement

I am currently making a self-processing form to display products that allows users to enter a quantity. I will then save the quantity in

```
$_POST['qty_entered']
```

when the users press the submit button. However, I also have an if statement to ensure that the users entered a valid quantity

```
    if (is_numeric($_POST['qty_entered'][0]) && is_int($_POST['qty_entered'][0]) && $_POST['qty_entered'][0] > 0) {
    print "'<tr><td>' test '</td>'";
}
else {
    $errors = true}
```

Then want to print a table with the invoice on the same page, only after the submit button is pressed and if the user entered a valid quantity. However, this code is not working:

```
if (array_key_exists ('submit_button', $_POST)) && $errors = false{
print "Invoice";
```

I also have a code at the beginning of the form to set $errors to false, and if $errors is true, it will print an error message. However, it is also not working because it doesn't display the error message when I type rubbish that would trigger the if statement such as "agfasgs" or "-1"

```
        $errors = false;
    if ($errors == true) {
print "Please enter postive whole numbers for quantity <br><br>";}
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This line does not have the brackets properly inserted. Also you need `==` or `===`(This enforces strict check) What you have currently assigns the variable. You need to check.

The `===` operator is supposed to compare exact content equality while the `==` operator would compare semantic equality

```
if (array_key_exists ('submit_button', $_POST)) && $errors = false{//This should have thrown an error though(FATAL)
```

It should be

```
if (array_key_exists ('submit_button', $_POST) && $errors == false){
```

Also, FYI, shouldnt this line

```
if (is_numeric($_POST['qty_entered'][0]) && is_int($_POST['qty_entered'][0]) && $_POST['qty_entered'][0] > 0) {
```

Be this: ?

```
if (is_numeric($_POST['qty_entered']) && is_int($_POST['qty_entered']) && $_POST['qty_entered'] > 0) {//access the post data properly
```

Comment: I have 5 quantities in the $_POST['qty_entered'] which is why I want it to refer to the first quantity, which is [0]. However the == fixed the fatal error that I was receiving. Thanks! However I still have the problem where it's not setting the $errors = TRUE when an error is found in the quantity

Comment: I am still stuck on the last part of the code where it sets $errors = TRUE if the if conditions aren't met.. var_dumping $errors returns false even though I typed in something weird such as -1 or sagsad

Comment: try remove the `is_int` condition

Comment: Actually, I have $errors at the beginning of the code so that it does not execute anything and just print an error message if those conditions aren't met.. So var_dumping $errors at the beginning returns false, however var_dumping $errors at the end after the if conditions returns true.. Why isn't it making the one at the beginning true as well since I thought a self-processing form would run itself again and it should change that boolean to true if there is an error

Answer (score 0):

`php
if (array_key_exists ('submit_button', $_POST)) && $errors = false{
print "Invoice";`

is not valid PHP: Your parens are wrong, and you're assigning `false` to `$errors` (you want `==`, not `=`)

```
if (array_key_exists('submit_button', $_POST) && $errors == false) {
```